# Linear Acceleration data on Z axis is giving around 0.9

Tags: android, accelerometer

So i was working for a project where i wanted to get the linear acceleration from the sensor.

But i have a problem over here.When i place my phone (Samsung Note 2 ie. GT-7100) onto the table with screen of the phone facing upwards, i am getting around 0.9-1 m/s^2 reading on the Z axis whereas the data on the Y and X axis is around 0.02-0.03 m/s^2 . I dont understand why is this so.

Can anyone out there please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance.Have a great day ahead.

Comment: It's probably sensor noise. Check if you are getting the same results in other devices also.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried checking on other devices as well. It was indeed some sensor noise.